# Proper way to get property name that is not found in the receiving json asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api `POST` Url that receives and object

```
[HttpPost]
public ResultObject SaveLetter(FormModel surplusForm)
```

If a property is not on the receiving json,It returns following message:

> "Required property 'PropertyName' not found in JSON. Path 'SomePath'

This property is decorated by `Required` Attribute

```
public class FormModel {
    [Required]
    public long? PropertyName{ get; set; }
    ///Other properties
    
}
```

I need to have my return message and need to find the `PropertyName` that is not in the receiving json, What is the best way to get it?

Actually it is an `exception` in model validation process, is there any way to get field name in case of exception in `modelState`?

Comment: you can remove the `Required` and check in the code whether that property is `null` or not in the response

Comment: In this case it could be sent by null value...in my case the property didn't exist at receiving json.

Comment: Then you can send the json string , declare the parameter as string and and check for the property value

Answer (score 1):

You can't use long? and  [Required]  together. If you make Property null it will break required attribute.  You have to fix your property. If you remove ? from long it will be requiered property by default and you don't neeed [Required] attribute:

```
 
    public long PropertyName{ get; set; }
```

or if you still want to validate you will have to do it this way:

```
[Range(1, long.Max, ErrorMessage = "Required")]
 public long PropertyName{ get; set; }
```

This should work too, although doesn' t have much sense:

```
[Range(1, long.Max, ErrorMessage = "Required")]
 public long? PropertyName{ get; set; }
```